# Найти все делители каждого числа в массиве

Tags: javascript

```js
function findDividers(start, end) {

  var dividers = [];
  for (let i = start + 1; i < end; i++) {
    dividers.push(i);
  }
  console.log(dividers);
}

findDividers(200, 500);
```

Есть массив чисел от **201** до **499**, и нужно для каждого из этих чисел найти сумму всех его делителей.

Я пытался записать ее как то так, но ничего не вышло, уже второй день ломаю голову, и все никак решение не найду

```js
var dividersDiv = [];
for (let j = 0; j < dividers.length; j++) {
  if (dividers % j == 0) {
    dividersDiv.push(j);
    console.log(dividersDiv);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function findDividers( start, end ) {
  const sumArr = [];

  for(let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    let sum = 0;
    
    for(let j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
      if(i % j === 0) sum += j;
    }
    
    sumArr.push(sum)
  }
  
  return sumArr;
}

console.log(findDividers(201, 499));
```

Answer (score 0):

Данный код будет складывать ВСЕ целочисленные делители (включая 1 и само число)

```js
function findDividers(start, end) {
  let answ = [];
  for (let i=start+1; i<end; i++){ //каждое число с 201 до 499
    let sum = 0;
    for (let j=1; j<=i; j++) { //каждая цифра с 1 до самого числа
      if (i%j==0) { sum += j;} //если остаток от деления = 0, то складываем
    }
    answ.push(sum); //добавляем в массив сумму
  }
  return answ;
}

console.log('Answer:');
console.log(findDividers(200, 500));
```

если нужна сумма не учитывая число и еденичку, то строчку

```
for (let j=1; j<=i; j++) {
```

меняем на

```
for (let j=2; j<i; j++) {
```